# Join attributes by location in GRASS GIS

Tags: grass-gis, fields-attributes, attribute-joins

I have spatially superimposed points in two layers from which I want to copy one column of attributes to the other layer. In QGIS you can do this with 'Join attributes by location' which worked great.

Now I want to write these steps in an R script using the R package rgrass7, which allows me to include GRASS GIS in R. Unfortunately I can't find a suitable equivalent to 'Join attributes by location' in GRASS GIS.

To give more background information:
I want to calculate the distance (as the crow flies) between locations and a river system. Therefore I calculated a network with `v.net.connect` and extracted the sections between the locations and the river with `v.select.intersect`. From this I got lines (of the sections), from which I could calculate the length with `v.to.db`, which I then saved in a column in the sections. Then I used `v.to.points` to create end nodes which got the length information. And now I want to copy exactly this length information into the attribute table of the locations. The places contain important information like a column with numbers which I need for further calculations and without I can't assign these points to other data later.

This may be a lot more complicated than it has to be, or 'thought around the corner', but in QGIS this method has worked.

A selected section between the location and the river with the length in the attribute table I want to transfer to sites:

[image: A selected section between the location and the river with the length in the attribute table I want to transfer to sites.]

Comment: Would v.what.vect help? It uploads vector values at positions of vector points to the table, https://grass.osgeo.org/grass78/manuals/v.what.vect.html

Comment: Thanks a lot! As far as I can see, only attributes from a table of a polygon map can be transferred to an attribute table of point vector maps, or vice versa. But I will try to generate polygons instead of points. In my example I get the error message: `ERROR: Incompatible column types`

Comment: @markusN Thanks a million, it worked! I just forgot to add `int` to `v.db.addcolumn`. It also works with the lines generated with `v.net.connect` so I don't need to create the nodes anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(written upon the discussion above)*

You may want to use [v.what.vect](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass-stable/manuals/v.what.vect.html) which uploads vector values at positions of vector points to the table. Importantly, run [v.db.addcolumn](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass-stable/manuals/v.db.addcolumn.html) beforehand to have a column in the attribute table which can be populated with the results.