# How do I update a polygon with values from a line in GRASS

Tags: grass-gis

I have a line map generated from r.stream.extract.  I also have a polygon map generated from r.stream.basins, using the raster stream layer generated from r.stream.extract.
I want to update the polygon layer with the category and one of the attributes of each line.
Each polygon contains one and only one line, which touches the boundary at either one or two points.

In PostGIS, I'd do something like the following:

```
UPDATE poly_table a 
SET line_cat = (
    SELECT line_cat FROM line_table b 
    WHERE st_contains(a.geom, b.geom)
);
```

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to do a relatively simple spatial join query. Does it have to be in Grass? In that case, perhaps v.what.vect +  v.db.addcolumn would help. Found it in this discussion: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/362128/join-attributes-by-location-in-grass-gis

Comment: Looks like v.what.vect and v.db.addcolumn would do the job in the general case - here it turns out the category is the same for my lines and polygons, because of how they were creeated, so a pure db solution would work.